# Mixed plane meshes

Tags: three.js

I have more than one plane at the same position and orientation with different colors and depending on the camera position the planes get mixed in different ways. The picture below shows the problem.

[image: mixed color planes]

How can this be solved in order to see the gray object perfectly and the black just as if it were behind? The green object is just a gray object outline.

I'm sure this problem has a name, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It disappears using the property

```
 depthTest: false
```

when defining the materials.